# Regex replacing word within string beginning with specific word (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, string, select, filter

I want to replace each occurrence of a specific word, but it has to be in a line which begins with another certain word.

Example text:

> *This* is some random *text* here
>
> *That* is also some random *text* here

I want only to select lines beginning with "**This**" and change the "**text**" to e.g. "word".

Result of fin&replace in Notepad++ would be:

> *This* is some random ***word*** here
>
> *That* is also some random *text* here

So far, I was able to select the line, no problem there: `(This.+)`
The problem is how to search for and replace the word "text", since I can't get the group/sub-pattern to work within itself, using `\1`.

I was able to select a string from and to a certain word, but can't figure out how to search within a line that is found.
I'm a regex rookie, so have patience. :)

Many thanks for sharing your brilliant thoughts!

Comment: is there more number of `text` on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

```
^This\b.*?\K\btext\b
```

Try this.Replace by `word`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jV9oV2/9

or

```
^(This\b.*?)\btext\b
```

Replace by `\1`.

Comment: Sweet, didn't know of the \K modifier! 

But It seems I can't replace the "text" with "word" in Notepad++ ... No matter what I put in the replace field. It just goes to next entry, unchanged. 
I found out that it only works with "Replace All" but not "Replace". Go figure ... :)

Comment: @SLVR which notepad version are you using?For me second option with `replace` is working